# Catalog Price Rules

Tags: catalog, price-rules

I want to know whether the catalog price rules are overriding the products special price?

For example, I want to apply certain percentage of discounts on product which already have special price but I want to apply new discounts with the help of the catalog price rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution for this is by self checking . if you test by applying catalog price rules to one product that already have special price.

But for my knowledge, the selling price will be the least of Catalog price rule and special price.

Example : If you have a product with Price :  $ 100. Special Price : 50 $.

If you apply 60 % off catalog rule for this, than selling price will be $40.

If you apply 40 % off catalog rule for this, than selling price will be $50.

Let meknow if you need any clarifications.....